# css media resolutions adjusting

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using CSS to adjust my on-screen elements to make my site look good on all resolutions. Six sample resolutions I'm trying to make my site work for:

1) 1024 x 768
2) 1152 x 864
3) 1280 x 800
4) 1280 x 960
5) 1280 x 1024
6) 1440 x 900

My code is as follows, but the code in #2 and #5 isn't responding. Any reason why the other four are but those two aren't?

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (max-height:768px) {
  (code here)
}

@media screen and (min-width:1152px) and (max-height:864px) {
  (code here) //not working
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:800px) {
  (code here)
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px) and (min-height:801px) and (max-height:960px) {
  (code here)
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px) and (min-height:961px) {
  (code here) //not working
}

@media screen and (min-width:1440px) {
  (code here)
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using height in your queries?

Comment: well if I don't then 1280x800 and 1280x960 and 1280x1024 aren't all going to look good (based on how my site is laid out). Only one of them will.

Comment: I don't believe this is the way to do it. True responsive design doesn't assume it will only be run on 6 different screens. For one thing, not everybody keeps their browser window maximised at all times, so you will have an infinite amount of possible window sizes and width to height ratios.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is 1) that an 1152 x 864 screen falls under media rule #4 too, and 2) that a 1280 x 960 screen isn't covered by rule #5.